# Recyclerview faces massive scroll lag when loading large number of items

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview

In app i'm having a activity which hosts a collapsing toolbar layout and a recycler view i got working properly however here issue is when i try to scroll my recyclerview it produces massive lags which in turn results in UI/UX shuttering here i'm trying to load large number of images in recycler view say 600 to 800 images are all loaded asynchronously with glide and couroutines inspite of this if i remove the images loading call of glide still recyclerview causes same lags like before.
I'm really unable to interpret the root cause this problem! Any help will be appreciated!

Here is my Adapter Class:
class MainFolderImagesAdapter :

```
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private var thumbPaths = ArrayList<String>()
    private val tempThumbPath = ArrayList<String>()
    private var context: Activity? = null
    private var albumName: String? = null
    private val al_selected_photo = ArrayList<Int>()
    private var mItemCLickAlbumImageListener: ItemCLickAlbumImageListener? = null
    private var mDatabaseHelper: DatabaseHelper? = null
    private var mBean: Bean? = null


    constructor(thumbPaths: ArrayList<String>, albumName: String, databaseHelper: DatabaseHelper, applicationContext: Activity, bean: Bean) {
        this.mBean = bean
        this.context = applicationContext
        this.albumName = albumName
        this.mDatabaseHelper = databaseHelper
        Share.selected_image_no.clear()
        this.thumbPaths = thumbPaths
    }

    protected inner class LoadingVH(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val mProgressBar: ProgressBar

        init {
            mProgressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pbar)

        }

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, i: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        var viewHolder1: RecyclerView.ViewHolder? = null
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)


        when (i) {
            ITEM -> {
                val view1 = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(R.layout.item_show_image, viewGroup, false)
                viewHolder1 = ViewHolder(view1)
                return ViewHolder(view1)
            }

            LOADING -> {
                val viewLoading = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_loading_list_item, viewGroup, false)
                viewHolder1 = LoadingVH(viewLoading)
            }
        }
        // View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_show_image, viewGroup, false);
        return viewHolder1!!
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int, payloads: List<Any>) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads)
        when (getItemViewType(position)) {
            ITEM -> {
                val movieVH = holder as ViewHolder


                if (payloads.contains("maulik")) {
                    movieVH.progress.visibility = View.GONE
                    movieVH.iv_complete.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                } else if (payloads.contains("123")) {
                    movieVH.iv_background.visibility = View.GONE
                    movieVH.iv_selected.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
            LOADING -> {
                val loadingVH = holder as LoadingVH
                loadingVH.mProgressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder1: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, i: Int) {
        //holder1.setIsRecyclable(false)
        when (getItemViewType(i)) {

            ITEM -> {
                val holder = holder1 as ViewHolder

                var uniqueID: Int?=null

                if (Share.checkUserType(context)) {
                    GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.Default) {
                        uniqueID = mDatabaseHelper!!.getImagesUniqueID(albumName,
                                getOriginalFilename(thumbPaths[i]), DatabaseHelper.IMAGES_TABLE)
                    }
                } else {
                    GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.Default) {
                        uniqueID = mDatabaseHelper!!.getImagesUniqueIDGuest(albumName,
                                getOriginalFilename(thumbPaths[i]), DatabaseHelper.IMAGES_TABLE)
                    }

                }

                if (Share.checkUserType(context)) {
                    //  if (SharedPrefs.getBoolean(context, SharedPrefs.AutoUploadEnable)) {
                    if (uniqueID!! > 0) {
                        holder.progress.visibility = View.GONE
                        holder.iv_complete.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    } else {
                        holder.progress.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        holder.iv_complete.visibility = View.GONE
                    }

                } else {
                    holder.progress.visibility = View.GONE
                    holder.iv_complete.visibility = View.GONE

                }

                if (!SharedPrefs.getBoolean(context, SharedPrefs.AutoUploadEnable)) {
                    holder.progress.visibility = View.GONE
                }
                if (al_selected_photo.size > 0) {
                    if (al_selected_photo.contains(uniqueID)) {
                        holder.iv_selected.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        holder.iv_background.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    } else {
                        holder.iv_selected.visibility = View.GONE
                        holder.iv_background.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                } else {
                    holder.iv_selected.visibility = View.GONE
                    holder.iv_background.visibility = View.GONE
                }

                try {
                GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.Default) {
                    var arr:ByteArray?=null
                    val op = GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.Default){
                     arr =  ImageEncryptDecrypt.decrypt(context, thumbPaths[i])
                    }
                    op.await()
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        Glide.with(context)
                                .load(arr)
                                .asBitmap()
                                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                                .thumbnail(0.9f)
                                .skipMemoryCache(false)
                                .centerCrop()
                                .placeholder(R.drawable.dummy_header_bg)
                                .listener(object : RequestListener<ByteArray, Bitmap> {
                                    override fun onException(e: Exception, model: ByteArray, target: Target<Bitmap>, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                                        return false
                                    }

                                    override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, model: ByteArray, target: Target<Bitmap>, isFromMemoryCache: Boolean, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                                        Log.e("Digan--->>", "onResourceReady: " + "redyyyyy")
                                        if (MainFolderImagesActivity.mDownloadImageDialog != null && MainFolderImagesActivity.mDownloadImageDialog!!.isShowing) {
                                            MainFolderImagesActivity.mDownloadImageDialog!!.dismiss()
                                            MainFolderImagesActivity.mDownloadImageDialog = null
                                        }
                                        Glide.get(context).clearMemory()
                                        return false
                                    }
                                })
                                .into(holder.all_image_iv_view)
                    }
                }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }



                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(object : OnSingleClickListener() {
                    override fun onSingleClick(v: View) {


                        if (Share.downloadComplete) {
                            if (uniqueID!! > 0) {
                                if (al_selected_photo.size > 0) {
                                    if (!al_selected_photo.contains(uniqueID!!)) {
                                        if (al_selected_photo.size < 20) {
                                            al_selected_photo.add(uniqueID!!)
                                            Share.selected_image_no.add(uniqueID)
                                            holder.iv_background.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                            holder.iv_selected.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                            if (mItemCLickAlbumImageListener != null) {
                                                if (al_selected_photo.size == 0) {
                                                    mItemCLickAlbumImageListener!!.itemClicked(i, al_selected_photo.size, holder.iv_selected)
                                                }
                                                MainFolderImagesActivity.tv_count.text = Share.selected_image_no.size.toString() + " Selected"
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(context!!.applicationContext, "you can select maximum 20 images", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        val pos = al_selected_photo.indexOf(uniqueID!!)
                                        al_selected_photo.removeAt(pos)
                                        Share.selected_image_no.removeAt(pos)
                                        holder.iv_background.visibility = View.GONE
                                        holder.iv_selected.visibility = View.GONE
                                        if (mItemCLickAlbumImageListener != null) {
                                            if (al_selected_photo.size == 0) {
                                                mItemCLickAlbumImageListener!!.itemClicked(i, al_selected_photo.size, holder.iv_selected)
                                            }
                                            MainFolderImagesActivity.tv_count.text = Share.selected_image_no.size.toString() + " Selected"
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    mBean!!.thumbPaths = thumbPaths
                                    val intent = Intent(context, ViewImageActivity::class.java)
                                    intent.putExtra("pos", holder.adapterPosition)
                                    intent.putExtra("fromWhere", "albumImages")
                                    context!!.startActivity(intent)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })

                holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener { v ->

                    if (Share.downloadComplete) {
                        //int uniqueID1 = mDatabaseHelper.getImagesUniqueID(albumName, getOriginalFilename(thumbPaths.get(i)), DatabaseHelper.IMAGES_TABLE);
                       var uniqueID1: Int?=null
                        if (Share.checkUserType(context)) {
                            GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.Default) {
                                uniqueID1 = mDatabaseHelper!!.getImagesUniqueID(albumName,
                                        getOriginalFilename(thumbPaths[i]), DatabaseHelper.IMAGES_TABLE)
                            }
                        } else {
                            GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.Default) {
                                uniqueID1 = mDatabaseHelper!!.getImagesUniqueIDGuest(albumName,
                                        getOriginalFilename(thumbPaths[i]), DatabaseHelper.IMAGES_TABLE)
                            }
                            System.gc()
                            Runtime.getRuntime().gc()
                        }

                        if (uniqueID!! > 0) {

                            if (al_selected_photo.size == 0) {
                                if (!al_selected_photo.contains(uniqueID1)) {

                                    if (al_selected_photo.size < 20) {

                                        Share.selected_image_no.add(uniqueID1)
                                        al_selected_photo.add(uniqueID1!!)
                                        holder.iv_selected.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                        holder.iv_background.visibility = View.VISIBLE


                                        if (mItemCLickAlbumImageListener != null) {
                                            mItemCLickAlbumImageListener!!.itemClicked(i, al_selected_photo.size, holder.iv_selected)
                                        }
                                        MainFolderImagesActivity.tv_count.text = Share.selected_image_no.size.toString() + " Selected"
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(context!!.applicationContext, "you can select maximum 20 images", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    val pos = al_selected_photo.indexOf(uniqueID1)
                                    Share.selected_image_no.removeAt(pos)
                                    al_selected_photo.removeAt(pos)
                                    holder.iv_selected.visibility = View.GONE
                                    holder.iv_background.visibility = View.GONE

                                    if (mItemCLickAlbumImageListener != null) {
                                        mItemCLickAlbumImageListener!!.itemClicked(i, al_selected_photo.size, holder.iv_selected)
                                    }
                                    MainFolderImagesActivity.tv_count.text = Share.selected_image_no.size.toString() + " Selected"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    true
                }
            }
            LOADING -> {
                val loadingVH = holder1 as LoadingVH

                loadingVH.mProgressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }


    }


    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (isLoadingAdded) {
            if (isLoadingAdded) ITEM else LOADING
        } else {
            if (position == thumbPaths.size - 1) LOADING else ITEM
        }
    }

    private fun getOriginalFilename(path: String?): String {
        return (if (path != null) {
            File(path).name
        } else path)!!
    }

    fun setItemClickListener(itemClickListener: ItemCLickAlbumImageListener) {
        this.mItemCLickAlbumImageListener = itemClickListener
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        Log.e("getItemCount", "getItemCount: " + thumbPaths.size)
        return thumbPaths.size
        //        /*return thumbPaths.size();*/
    }


    fun unSelectAll() {

        for (i in al_selected_photo.indices) {
            GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.Default) {
                val path = mDatabaseHelper!!.getImagesStringFromUniqID(al_selected_photo[i], null, DatabaseHelper.IMAGES_TABLE)
                notifyItemChanged(thumbPaths.indexOf(path), "123")
            }
        }
        Share.selected_image_no.clear()
        al_selected_photo.clear()
    }

    fun removeItems(selectedItemsThumbs: ArrayList<String>) {

        for (i in selectedItemsThumbs.indices) {
            thumbPaths.remove(selectedItemsThumbs[i])
            notifyItemRemoved(thumbPaths.indexOf(selectedItemsThumbs[i]))
            notifyItemRangeChanged(thumbPaths.indexOf(selectedItemsThumbs[i]), itemCount)
        }
        (context as MainFolderImagesActivity).changeCount(thumbPaths.size)
        al_selected_photo.clear()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun updateResult(imageItems: ArrayList<String>) {
        thumbPaths.addAll(imageItems)
        notifyItemRangeInserted(0, itemCount)

        (context as MainFolderImagesActivity).changeCount(thumbPaths.size)

    }

    fun updateResult1(imageItems: ArrayList<String>) {


        thumbPaths.addAll(imageItems)

        notifyItemRangeInserted(itemCount, thumbPaths.size)

    }


    internal inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var all_image_iv_view: ImageView
        var iv_selected: ImageView
        var iv_background: ImageView
        var iv_complete: ImageView
        var progress: ProgressBar

        init {

            all_image_iv_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.all_image_iv_view)
            iv_background = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_background)
            iv_selected = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_selected)
            progress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress)
            iv_complete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_complete)

            val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
            context!!.windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
            val width = displayMetrics.widthPixels

            all_image_iv_view.requestLayout()
            all_image_iv_view.layoutParams.height = width / 3
            all_image_iv_view.layoutParams.width = width / 3

            iv_background.setBackgroundColor(mBean!!.themeColor)

        }
    }

    fun add(response: String) {

        if (!thumbPaths.contains(response)) {
            thumbPaths.add(0, response)
            notifyItemInserted(0)
            notifyItemRangeChanged(0, itemCount)
            (context as MainFolderImagesActivity).rcv_images.scrollToPosition(0)
            (context as MainFolderImagesActivity).changeCount(thumbPaths.size)
        } else {
            Logs.e("add", "add: ")
            notifyItemChanged(thumbPaths.indexOf(response), "maulik")
        }

    }

    fun setValue(thumbPath: String, path: String) {
        if (thumbPaths.contains(thumbPath)) {
            Logs.e("setValue", "setValue: " + thumbPaths.indexOf(thumbPath))
            thumbPaths[thumbPaths.indexOf(thumbPath)] = path
            notifyItemChanged(thumbPaths.indexOf(path), "maulik")
        }
    }

    fun addAll(postItems: List<String>) {
        for (response in postItems) {
            add(response)
        }
    }



    companion object {
        private var isLoadingAdded = false

        // View Types
        private val ITEM = 0
        private val LOADING = 1
    }
}
```

Note : I've already added these flags in recyclerview

```
rcv_images.setHasFixedSize(true)
rcv_images.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
rcv_images.setItemViewCacheSize(20)
```

Here's the link to xml code:

```
https://pastebin.com/F9wrrYpA
```

Comment: Are you performing database queries on the main thread?

Comment: Can you show us the XML Layout of your RecyclerView? It shouldn't load so many images if they aren't required all at once.

Comment: mostly all database queries are done from async class @Isak

Comment: @R.Coder What about the call of `getOriginalFilename `? It creates a File which is costly.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann yes that call is indeed happening in mainthread

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann should i move it to background?

Comment: That's what I would try next, yes. Although you're not writing it to the file system.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann  thanks a lot i moved database query in background which improved the performance but still there are some noticeable lags and shutters and other optimisations you suggest?

Comment: @R.Coder Yes, the decoding of bitmaps `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` as stated here:
"Any long-running computations and operations such as decoding a bitmap, accessing the disk, or performing network requests should be done on a separate background thread. "
https://developer.android.com/guide/background/

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann i'm loading that part with glide and coroutines right now it's not there in code i pasted here old code so it's just removed in current one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200647/discussion-between-r-coder-and-alexander-hoffmann).